# In zod How to make email field optional depending on enum value from another field

Tags: zod

I've seen several similar posts, but I can't figure out how to make a field optional if another field has specific value.

Basically I want email field to be optional only if stakeholderType is 'ORGANIZATION', otherwise email is required

I've tried superRefine, but it's not working:

```
export const newStakeholderFormSchema = z
  .object({
    fullName: z.string().min(1, {
      message: 'Name is required',
    }),
    email: z.string().email().optional().or(z.literal('')),

    profilePicture: z.object({
      uri: z.string().optional(),
      hash: z.number().optional(),
      blob: z.any().optional(),
    }),
    message: z.string().optional(),
    stakeholderType: z
      .enum(['USER', 'ORGANIZATION', 'ADMIN', 'EDITOR'])
      .optional(),
  })
  .superRefine(({ stakeholderType, email }, ctx) => {
    // Here we add the extra check to assert the field exists when
    // the "Other" goal is present.
    if (stakeholderType !== 'ORGANIZATION') {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: 'custom',
        path: ['email'],
        params: {
          email: z.string().email(),
        },
      });
    }
  });
```